# Is Odoo programming related?

Tags: discussion, tags, questions, scope

I've seen a fair number of questions such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77052090/is-there-a-possible-way-that-i-can-connect-odoo-sales-to-odoo-calendar) that don't look like programming questions to me but I know nothing about [odoo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/odoo).

Comment: It's probably as programming-related as Microsoft Office is: not at all by default, but you can certainly ask programming-related questions about it.

Comment: As with all such systems: Modifying Odoo, writing plugins for Odoo and similar things -> on-topic. Help with Odoo from a user perspective -> off-topic. Configuring Odoo: depends of who you ask.

Comment: Looking at the top-scored Q&A tagged [tag:Odoo], I am honestly wondering if the tag is applied randomly. Many of those very highly scored questions seem to have nothing to do with it.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I think the product attracts a lot people who want a free ERP system but are not professional programmers.  So they tag as odoo because they know no better, even if the problem can be decomposed to "how do I install psycopg2" or similar.

Comment: Followup question: will off-topic questions about on-topic tags ever stop pouring in? Nope, never. And a good many of the off-topic ones will be answered without prejudice.  That's the situation that has been created by making it an "it depends", as per BDL's excellent comment answer. Compounded by the fact that the actual rules about what is on-topic are written in a way that promotes selective reading.

Comment: It shows why a good tag guidance is important. Even though many users don't read them, they do help in curating. I hope someone can improve the guidance (i.e. explaining when questions on the subject are on topic).

Comment: @GertArnold Agree. There are far too many tags with little to no guidance whatsoever.

Comment: @GertArnold I've added some guidance to the tag, replacing the previous marketing blurb (though I am not convinced many people read the guidance, much less pay heed to it).

Answer (score 6):

Questions about Odoo can certainly be programming related. The Community Edition source code is published on GitHub and there is an ecosystem of plugins, extensions written by third parties.  Questions about coding Odoo are therefore on-topic, but as [BDL](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2579738/bdl) observes in [their comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426330/is-odoo-programming-related#comment971557_426330), questions about configuration or usage (such as the question linked by the OP) are likely to be off-topic.